# LG P500 Rooting Isuue

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, lg-optimus-one

I got a LG P500 Android device and I want to root it.
The device is on stock ROM, android 2.3.3 V20e.
Should I use SuperOneClick? And if so, how can I reboot my phone after the SuperOneClick procedure is finished? If I power off my device and then turn it back on, will it break it, or is this "reboot"?

Answer (score 1):

Just few minutes before I again rooted my LgP500 running v2.3.3 stock v20d. I used SuperOneClick v2.3.3 and rooting was just a cake walk. I charged my phone fully and installed Lg's drivers and enabled USB debugging support. In the SuperOneClick's UI, I just clicked Root and waited for few tense minutes. Phone restarted automatically and after that the UI said rooting was successful.

It is not clear what you ask about booting, I just switched on normally and phone works normally.

Update: Found a [link](http://www.androidauthority.com/optimus-one-p500-root-69706/) as asked...

Answer (score 0):

Download root master (.apk) thent install it and start rooting, it creates an app 'super user' which gives root permission, and enjoy root
Link:- http://www.9apps.com/android-apps/Root-Master/